# Needing help to place swing components correctly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

In order to pass a college course, i need to code a software with JAVA and the swing API. However I have some issues to place my components like I want :

I want to place some components in the moodPanel:
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfYxh.png)

Which layout should I use for the moodPanel and which is the best Way to get the components like in the second draw ?

Edit : I'm currently trying to apply the solution below, but I have some problems :
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpY5g.png)

```
public MoodPanel(){
    super();

    this.setBackground(new Color(255, 255,0));

    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    this.choicePanel = new JPanel();
    this.choicePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.choicePanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    this.statPanel = new JPanel();
    this.statPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());



    this.lIdTweet= new JLabel();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridwidth=3;
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;
    c.weightx=0.0;
    c.anchor =GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    this.choicePanel.add(this.lIdTweet,c);

    this.moodGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    this.JRBad = new JRadioButton("Mauvais");
    this.JRBad.setActionCommand("0");
    this.JRBad.setVisible(false);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;
    c.weightx=0.0;
    this.choicePanel.add(this.JRBad,c);



    this.JRNeutral = new JRadioButton("Neutre");
    this.JRNeutral.setActionCommand("2");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx=1.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,70, 0, 0);
    this.choicePanel.add(this.JRNeutral,c);
    this.JRNeutral.setVisible(false);




    this.JRGood = new JRadioButton("Bon");
    this.JRGood.setVisible(false);
    this.JRGood.setActionCommand("4");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx=0.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0, 0, 0);
    this.choicePanel.add(this.JRGood,c);





    this.moodGroup.add(this.JRBad);
    this.moodGroup.add(this.JRNeutral);
    this.moodGroup.add(this.JRGood);



    this.buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    this.buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    this.intializingListener();
    this.btnAddToList = new JButton("Ajouter");
    this.btnAddToList.addActionListener(OKAction);
    this.MPClose= new JButton("Fermer");
    this.MPClose.addActionListener(CancelAction);
    this.buttonPanel.add(btnAddToList);
    this.buttonPanel.add(MPClose);
    this.buttonPanel.setVisible(false);
    this.buttonPanel.setSize(new Dimension(this.buttonPanel.getPreferredSize().width,this.btnAddToList.getPreferredSize().height));
    this.buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(60, 90, 60));





    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;
    c.weightx=0.0;
    c.gridwidth=3;
    this.choicePanel.add(buttonPanel,c);
    this.add(choicePanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(statPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: There's a possible `BorderLayout`, maybe a `FlowLayout` or `GridLayout` or you could just be lazy and use a `GridBagLayout` depending on how complex the UI is

Comment: But with a flowLayout you can't go up to down, right ?

Comment: You need to use multiple layouts

Comment: Yeah I know but which layouts ?

Comment: I left you a list, which ones you use will depend on how you want space to divided between the child components when the parent container is larger or smaller then the preferred size

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to designing layouts, you need to break down each section in needs and responsibilities, while you could actually do the whole layout using `GridBagLayout`'s, it's probably way over kill.

Instead, you can use a series of compounding layouts, each adding to what the previous layouts where doing, for example...

If we look at the main layout, I see two main areas, more or less...

[image]

this just screams `BorderLayout` (again `GridBagLayout` could work)

Now, we start focusing into the `NORTH` section

[image]

The question that needs to be answered here is, are all those three sections equal in height?  If they are, then `GridLayout` could work, if not, then I'd probably be leaning towards `GridBagLayout`

The last two sections are almost the same...

[image][image]

You need to answer the question, are all the elements going to be given the same about of horizontal space or not?  If they size equally, then you can use a `GridLayout`, if not, you could use either a `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` depending on your needs and desires.

Try never to look at the "whole" UI and try and solve it in one single step, most times, you want to break it down into areas of functionality, which will also allow you to separate the areas of responsibility in your code and generate self contained units of work from which you can base you classes on.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi, I'm try to use your solution, I have added some information in my post.